# Different results between iOS 7.1 and 8 while using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios7.1, xcode6

I am practicing swift by writing a simple game. However, I noticed something weird happening. I am getting different results when I run my app on iOS 7.1 compared to iOS 8. I am trying to downcast an SKNode to a custom class that I wrote called CircleNode, which inherits from SKSpriteNode. Here is the class:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class CircleNode: SKSpriteNode {
    var _hasMoved = false
    var _touchingCircles:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var _isTouchingObject = false
    var _selectedForDeletion = false
    var _isBeingTouched = false
    var _xOffset:CGFloat = 0
    var _yOffset:CGFloat = 0

    func addTouchingCircle(touchingCircle:CircleNode)    {
        _touchingCircles.addObject(touchingCircle)
        _isTouchingObject = true
    }

    func removeAllCircles(){
        self._selectedForDeletion = true

        for circ :CircleNode! in _touchingCircles {
            if circ._selectedForDeletion == false {
                circ.removeAllCircles()
            }
        }
        self.removeFromParent()
    }   
}
```

The code that is resulting in weird results is :

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let locationInScene = touch.locationInNode(self)
            var selectedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(locationInScene)

            let node = selectedNode as? CircleNode

            if node {
                println("NODE FOUND:circle")
            } else {
                println("NULL")
            }
     }
}
```

In iOS 8, when I click on one of the on screen circles, it prints "NODE FOUND:circle". However, when I do the same on iOS 7.1 it prints "NULL". I have been trying to figure out why this is happening for days, but I can't seem to figure it out. It seems like in iOS 8, `var selectedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(locationInScene)` actually returns my CircleNode, but in iOS 7.1, it doesn't recognize the node. Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you print selectedNode without casting it?

Comment: In iOS 7.1, the result of printing selectedNode without casting it is: `<SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{0, 0}, {320, 568}}`

In iOS 8, the result is: `<SKSpriteNode> name:'circle' texture:[<SKTexture> 'blueCircle.png' (128 x 128)] position:{114, 478} size:{38.911911010742188, 38.911911010742188} rotation:0.00`

Comment: Well, I have no experience in SpriteKit, but it looks like that on 7.1 instead of getting your node you are getting its parent node, the whole scene.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you, I just don't understand why. I'm sure there is something that I am forgetting, I am pretty new to SpriteKit as well. However, most of my confusion is coming from the differences between iOS 8 and 7.1

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an issue with the way the XCode templates have changed between XCode 6.0 and 6.1 that causes problems when working with SpriteKit scenes in Swift.

The problem is actually with the initialization of the SKScene from your controller, not the node itself: XCode 6.1 implements the 'unarchiveFromFile' extension method which doesn't appear to work well with Swift on iOS7.1

I got round this by using the following extension:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile<T: SKScene>(file : NSString) -> T {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks")
        var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
        var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData!)

        archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
        let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as T
        archiver.finishDecoding()
        return scene
    }

    class func safeInit<T: SKScene>(size: CGSize, _ skFile: NSString) -> T {
        let currentVersion = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion
        let isIOS8 = currentVersion.compare("8.0", options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) != NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
        if isIOS8 {
            let scene = T.unarchiveFromFile(skFile)
            scene.size = size
            return scene as T
        } else {
            return T(size: size)
        }
    }
}
```

And then calling this from your controller using the following code:

```
    let skView = self.view as SKView
    let scene = GameScene.safeInit(skView.bounds.size, "GameScene") as GameScene
```

That seems to work for me. It feels like a bit of a hack but I can't see any alternative option that actually works.